# $ionicPopup are not showing at botton

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I am new at ionic framework and angular Js. I am using Confirm style ionic popup, why buttons are not showing in the bottom of the popup.

Here is the updated codepen.

```
[http://codepen.io/skpatel/pen/ZGwGOO][1]
```

Please help me, I am having this issue since a long. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: I have updated the code pen, though everything is correct but sometimes the popup works differently. All you need to do is

```
.popup-body {
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    height:100%; 
}
```

EDIT: Well the functionality that you want should be done in a "$ionicModal", but since you want to do it in "$ionicPopup". PS: you shouldn't use `ion-content` in a pop-up. Just a info.

I have updated the [Code-Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVPJbG):

Comment: where you have given this CSS?

Comment: same place where you have given    `.popup {
  width: 90% !important;
  height: 90%;
  max-height: 90% !important;
}`   mark it as accepted answer ?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have seen that but you have not used anywhere in html or .js file. That was my question. It worked but not expected i think its popup problem. I will upload screenshot again

Comment: Here, I can see buttons at bottom part, but My list data appears behind buttons in scroll mode. 
Shall I do something like Footer bar here? Which would make these two  buttons as like footer bar and my list or main content will be reside between top header bar (Accordian List text has been written) and footer bar (two buttons).

Comment: Yes it worked but not expected. I explained you problem above

Comment: Not really, Actually I can see buttons at bottom but not like footer bar.

Comment: I think I need to add buttons in my popup template.html file and need to change ionic popup type to popup.show() type